# C# - Create class to received list from HTTP Post response (XML)

Tags: c#, xml

I tried to received HTTP POST Reponse which is in XML Format, and has List inside using class

this is XML from server :

```
<list_bulk_response>
      <status_code>1100</status_code>
      <status_text>OK</status_text>
      <list_request>
             <request_bulk>
                   <request_status_code>1100</request_status_code>
                   <request_status_text>OK</request_status_text>
                   <id>1</id>
             </request_bulk>
             <request_bulk>
                   <request_status_code>1100</request_status_code>
                   <request_status_text>OK</request_status_text>
                   <id>2</id>
             </request_bulk>
             .... 
             .... 
             .... 
</list_request>
</list_bulk_response>
```

After search in many source, i try this :

```
public class list_bulk_response : 
{
    public string status_code { get; set; }
    public string status_text { get; set; }
    public list_request list_request { get; set; }

}
public class list_request
{
    public List<request_bulk> request_bulk { get; set; }

}
public class request_bulk
{
    public string request_status_code { get; set; }
    public string request_status_text { get; set; }
    public string id{ get; set; }
}
```

and this :

```
public class list_bulk_response : KenjaloApi
{
    public List<list_request> list_request { get; set; }

}
public class list_request
{
    public request_bulk request_bulk { get; set; }

}
public class request_bulk
{
    public string request_status_code { get; set; }
    public string request_status_text { get; set; }
    public string request_date { get; set; }
    public string transaction_id { get; set; }
    public string priority { get; set; }
    public string sender { get; set; }
    public string dr_url { get; set; }

}
```

but still failed to received list that inside XML

**UPDATE**
this is my code to deserialize :

```
    public static T deserializeXMLtoClass<T>(string input) where T : class
    {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
            {
                return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
                sr.Close();
            }
    }
```

Any wrong in my class?

Comment: You need to show the code that you used to deserialize.

Comment: @Enigmativity : i have add my code to deserialize in my question. thanks

Comment: You've mentioned it's failing, but with what exception? Can you show us the exception and the line on which it is failing?

Comment: @HermanCordes : no any exeption, just List<request_bulk> always null although list of request bulk is exists in XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first model is almost correct. You are just missing a simple *hint* `[XmlElement("request_bulk")]`

```
var t = deserializeXMLtoClass<list_bulk_response>(xmlstring);
```

---

```
public class list_bulk_response
{
    public string status_code { get; set; }
    public string status_text { get; set; }
    public list_request list_request { get; set; }

}
public class list_request
{
    [XmlElement("request_bulk")]
    public List<request_bulk> request_bulk { get; set; }

}
public class request_bulk
{
    public string request_status_code { get; set; }
    public string request_status_text { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
using (Stream httpResponseStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
{
    XDocument responseXML = XDocument.Load(httpResponseStream);

    IEnumerable<XElement> listBulkResponseElements = responseXML.Root.
    Elements("list_bulk_response");

    foreach (XElement lbre in listBulkResponseElements)
    {
        list_bulk_response lbr = new list_bulk_response();
        request_bulk rb = new request_bulk();

        // Access the values with Element(valueName).value like this
        lbr.statuscode = lbre.Element("statuscode").value;
        lbr.statustext = lbre.Element("statustext").value;

        // For nested elements you need to add extra Element(valueName)s like this
        rb.request_status_code = Root.Element("list_request").Elements("request_bulk").
        Element("request_status_code").value;

        // Notice that "Element" is used where you only have one of them like with your 
        // "list_bulk_response" and "Elements" is used where you have multiple ones 
        // like with "request_bulk"

        // And so on

        // Now you need to decide what do do with your objects
    }
}
```